# Windows 10 Firewall warns about being disabled on every login

Tags: windows, windows-10, firewall

I've disabled the Windows Firewall on the devices in my home network because I just don't need it and its only annoying.

Windows unnecessarily warns me about this every time I log on which is incredibly annoying, especially because the notification appears at a seemingly random time within the first 15 minutes of logging in and not just always at the very start. Is there any way to make it stop bugging me about it?

[image: the annoying notification]

---

Text in case anyone is trying to find this in a search engine in the future:

*Firewall & network proection*
**Turn on Windows Firewall**
*Windows Firewall is turned off. Tap or click to turn it on.*

Comment: @CameronTacklind: I'm on the latest Windows 10 version, and I can see this message in the Action Center, but I'm not getting it as a popup. Is it the same on your side?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can disable Windows Defender Firewall with Group Policy. In the administrative templates for the computer, go to *Network | Network Connections | Windows Defender Firewall | Standard Profile* (or *Domain Profile* if your computers are connected to a domain network) and set "Windows Defender Firewall: Protect all network connections" to Disabled. As the policy description says:

> If you disable this policy setting, Windows Defender Firewall does not run. This is the only way to ensure that Windows Defender Firewall does not run and administrators who log on locally cannot start it.

With the policy disabled, the Windows Security dashboard says "no action needed" for firewall & network protection yet confirms that the firewall is off if you open that section. Notifications about the firewall are disabled, but other Windows Security notifications (e.g. about threats found) still appear.

To apply that policy setting without a Group Policy editor, navigate to or create the Registry key...

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\StandardProfile
```

...(or `DomainProfile` for a domain network) and create a DWORD value named `EnableFirewall` set to 0, then reboot.

Comment: Make sure you have the standard Windows Firewall "Enabled" or the same notifications will continue to happen. Otherwise, this works great! Thanks for the answer! I've been looking for the right way to do this for too long. Bounty well earned.

Comment: Setting `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\StandardProfile\EnableFirewall` to zero did not work for me. I keep getting the annoying message every time I log in. I **want** to have Windows Firewall disabled. I just want to get rid of the stupid message.

Comment: @Henke This still appears to work for me on fully updated Windows 10 21H2. You need to have Windows Firewall enabled before changing the setting as mentioned by Cameron, and might need to press "turn on" in the Windows Security app and relog, but according to `wf.msc` the firewall remains off.

Comment: Thanks! For your helpful answer and for the comment-answer. (I used your solution to write an answer of my own – hopefully for the benefit of my future self.)

Answer (score 3):

> the notification appears at a seemingly random time within the first
> 15 minutes of logging in

Yes – this adds to the frustration as it makes it harder to
reproduce (and understand the cause of) the message.

#### 0. A method to reproduce the message instantly

To reproduce the message instantly, try the following.

Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, click **Update & Security**,
then **Windows Security** (in the left pane),
then **Firewall & network protection** (in the right pane).

This opens a new **Windows Security** window with
**Firewall & network protection** pre-chosen in the left pane.
As you can see, there are three types of network :
[Domain, Private, and Public](https://techgenix.com/windows-firewall-domain-networks-private-networks-public-networks/).

[image: Windows Security > Firewall & network protection]

---

Now click on any of these three, for example the **Domain network**.
Then – under **Microsoft Defender Firewall** – turn the switch
**Off**.
Expect to see the annoying message appearing in the lower right
corner as in the picture below.

[image: When trying to run Windows Update, expect to see an error.]

<sup>^ click to enlarge</sup>

#### 1. Adjust a value in the registry

To follow the advice given in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1614769), do as follows.

1. Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type `cmd`, hold down
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   <sup>1</sup>
2. Paste

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\StandardProfile^
 /v EnableFirewall /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If and when you want to *revert* this setting, paste

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\StandardProfile^
 /v EnableFirewall /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
<sup>2</sup>

If you still have a **Windows Security** window open, make sure
you close it.
Then go to **Settings** > **Update & Security** > **Windows Security**
and click on **Firewall & network protection** (in the right pane).
This reopens the **Windows Security** window.
<sup>3</sup>
Expect to see the Domain firewall still on, but the Private and
Public firewalls to be *off*.
Personally, I would have preferred to have the firewall for the Public
network on, but that doesn't seem to be possible to combine with
having the firewall for the Private network off.

[image: The Private and Public networks are off.]

#### 2. The user and the administrator

If you click on **Private network**, expect to see a window as shown
below.
A message says *This setting is managed by your administrator*.
Apparently, the Microsoft view is that as a *user* I tried to set the
firewall **on**, but when I ran the registry hack to **disable** the
firewall then I played the role of being my own *administrator*.
(That's a bit humorous, isn't it?)

[image: The Private and Public networks are off.]

#### 3. Final remarks

In the end, I have decided ***not*** to prevent these notifications.
– For two reasons.

1. I seldomly log out and back in again.
   And I normally restart my computer more seldomly than once a day.
   (Putting the computer to sleep and rewakening it, doesn't seem to
   trigger any notifications.)
2. More importantly, I have noticed that the suggested registry
   setting prevents not only Windows notifications, but also
   notifications when I get a new message in Facebook Messenger.
   This I don't want.

#### References

- [Windows Firewall: Domain, Private, and Public Networks](https://techgenix.com/windows-firewall-domain-networks-private-networks-public-networks/)
- [Answer that I borrow heavily from](https://superuser.com/a/1614769)

---

<sup>1</sup>
Holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> opens the command line
*as administrator*.

<sup>2</sup>
In fact, the `WindowsFirewall` registry key didn't exist until I
created it, so I might as well run :
`reg delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall /f`

Make sure that you know what you are doing before running any of my
registry hacks. – For your own sake: better safe than sorry!
If you feel the slightest bit uncertain, you might be better off
doing the changes manually.
Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type `regedit` and hit
<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, paste
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall` and press
<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
After visually checking what the `WindowsFirewall` key contains, if
you decide to delete it,
right-click the `WindowsFirewall` key and click **Delete**.

<sup>3</sup>
It doesn't seem to be possible to refresh the **Windows Security**
window while it's open.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable these notifications.

Go to Start -> Settings (gear) -> Update & Security -> Windows Security -> Firewall & network protection.

Scroll to the bottom of the page where you have the links to other settings, and click Firewall notification settings.

Below Notifications, click Manage notifications.

Turn everything off or take the time to read and decide which notifications you want to keep, but given your question, you likely want to turn them all off.

Comment: Those settings disable notifications about firewall actions. There's no setting about firewall being disabled.

Answer (score 1):

This one thing was the only thing that helped me out of the many attempts I made.

Please enter to prompt `Windows+R (WIN+R)` for open Run dialog and put `gpedit.msc` into it and hit enter.

**Local Group Policy Editor**
And

```
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Security\Notifications
```

[image: Local Group Policy Editor]
[image: Local Group Policy Editor Detail]

Comment: For people that do not know how to invoke the editor, perhaps you could edit your answer and add that in.

Answer (score 1):

All of the above ideas do not work. The only thing that works is this :

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications]
"NoToastApplicationNotification"=dword:00000001
"NoToastApplicationNotificationOnLockScreen"=dword:00000001

my windows is Windows 10 Pro 18362. Firewall is turned off, no notifications at all.
Enjoy.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me where nothing else did.